# preg_match problem

Tags: php, regex

I have written this function:

```
public static function isDecimal($value, $places = 2)
    {
        if(preg_match("/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{".$places."})?$/", $value)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Which is designed to test whether the value being entered is a number/decimal number. However, if I enter the number "23c.32" or "2b3.23" it returns it as true. Can anybody point out where the fault lies in my regex?

Comment: It works just fine here. Are you sure the problem is inside your function, and not somewhere near the function call?

Comment: Also, though a bit off topic: Double quoted strings expand variables, so you can put $places inside the string itself, without dot-concatenating.

Comment: @Pianosaurus - Thanks! If you put this as an answer I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just fine here. The problem must be somewhere near the function call.

Answer (score 1):

That regex is fine, it returns false if you use it with the examples you provided.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) and [is_float()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php).

Built in functions that appear to do what you are looking for.